# How can I do a Hybris API REST for generate download excel file?

Tags: spring, rest, swagger-ui, sap-commerce-cloud

Hi experts i'm trying to create a new endpoint that creates a new excel file but I don't have any idea to do this.

I found this example and I think it can help me to create the file for excel but i'm not sure, by the way if this works I don't know how to download it.

```
File file = File.createTempFile(prefix,".csv")
byte[] bom = [0xEF, 0xBB, 0xBF]; // small "hack" to make this work with Microsoft Excel
FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(file, bom, false);

FileUtils.writeStringToFile(file, "Something;Something;Something;Something;Something\n", "UTF-8", true);`
```

I expect a swagger endpoint for generate a new excel file and download it.

Comment: You should learn about SAP OCC, then you can create a REST API.